# Exchange 2013 - no admin and mailbox audit logs

Tags: exchange, logging, exchange-2013, audit

I recently installed on a new network Exchange 2013. I noticed that my admin audit logs and mailbox audit logs are empty. I did Search-AdminAuditLog and Search-MailboxAuditLog and it brought no results,even though it is enabled in each mailbox config, and in the AdminAuditLogConfig. I used the Get-MailboxFolderStatistics to see the size of the audit folder, but I found it does not exist - there is no audits subfolder in any mailbox.

What is the problem with my exchange? How can I fix it to write logs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check it is enabled.
Get-AdminAuditLogConfig | FL AdminAuditLogEnabled

Are you using an account with the required permissions? If the permissions aren't correct then you cannot see anything.

Comment: Hi, i've checked that, and the AdminAuditLogEnabled is enabled. I'm using the administrator account of the exchange, which is in Organization Management

Answer (score 0):

I successfully solved my problem! My database index was corrupted, so I needed to repair it. A guide for it can be found here:
http://practical365.com/exchange-server/fix-failed-database-content-index-exchange-2013/
Thanks everyone :)